# C# not completing if statement on id4

Tags: c#

On id4 it is not completing if statement and output gets messed up by a line.
Looks like it is not completing and cannot get to the else statement.
By the way to be more specific I'm trying to make a five-in-a-row display function.
Hopefully we can make this work. (Using System is in the code)

```
namespace amoba_fel3
{
    class FiveInARowBoard
    {
        public FiveInARowBoard( int size )
        {
            m_size = size;
            m_board = new int[m_size, m_size];
        }

        public void set( int row, int col, int val )
        {
            m_board[row, col] = val;
        }

        public void draw()
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < m_size; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < m_size; col++)
                {
                    if (m_board[row, col] == 0)
                        Console.Write("[.]");
                    else if (m_board[row, col] == 1)
                        Console.Write("[O]");
                    else if (m_board[row, col] == 2)
                        Console.Write("[X]");
                    else if (m_board[row, col] == 3)
                        Console.Write(" " + cords[col] + " ");
                    else if (m_board[row, col] == 4)
                        if (col >= 10)
                            Console.Write(numcords[row]);
                        else
                            Console.Write(" " + numcords[row] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private int[] numcords = new int[] { 0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
                                            12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
        private char[] cords = "AABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
        private int m_size;
        private int[,] m_board;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FiveInARowBoard board = new FiveInARowBoard(20);

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                board.set(0, i, 3);
                board.set(i, 0, 4);
            }

            board.draw();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yacc "main should be outside the class" no? main should be inside a class, it's a method.

Comment: @yacc: "main should be outside the class" That sounds unlikely - a method can't be directly inside a namespace, unless whatever "id4" is has a very odd idea of C#.

Comment: True, I got that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, what you're asking is how to properly align the rows in the grid, since numbers greater than 9 have two digits and offset the grid by one character. The mistake you have made is in comparing against the `col` variable instead of the `row` variable.

Your code currently has these lines:

```
else if (m_board[row, col] == 4)
   if (col >= 10)
      Console.Write(numcords[row]);
   else
      Console.Write(" " + numcords[row] + " ");
```

Change them to this:

```
else if (m_board[row, col] == 4)
   if (row >= 10) // check the row not the col
      Console.Write(numcords[row] + " "); // still need a trailing space
   else
      Console.Write(" " + numcords[row] + " "); // leading space when single digit
```